# Electron - Reload mainWindow from another window

Tags: javascript, electron

For an electron project, I am using two window instances.
One mainWindow & another one for preferences. After saving some preferences in the settingsWindow the mainWindow should reload (simple reload via CTRL+R / F5).

mainWindow with Content (a map)
settingsWindow with Configuration fields like map marker color and other which will be saved into a JSON after click event (saving is already working).

a simple reload of the mainWindow would be enough to load the "updated" settings. Actually, the user has always to close the whole electron app to load the updated settings.

've seen that something like that should be possible with the remote module. But I did not find any examples besides the official docs where this scenario isn't noted as far as I can see.

what do I have to write into mainWindow.html & settingsWindow.html to force a reload of the mainWindow out of settingsWindow?